# How to create a flag to include/exclude rows from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

How to create a flag to include/exclude rows from a df in python. Example - `flag = 1` will include all rows from the df and `flag = 0` will include all rows except `col2 = 'a'`

```
row col1 col2
1    1     a
2    2     a
3    3     b
4    4     c
```

Expected output - `flag =1` should populate all rows, `flag = 0` should only populate rows 3,4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of rules with strings in a dictionary and apply them using the `df.query` method.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": np.random.randint(4, size=10), 
    "col2": np.random.choice(list("abcd"), 10)})

print(df)
   col1 col2
0     0    b
1     3    c
2     1    a
3     0    d
4     3    c
5     3    a
6     3    a
7     3    a
8     1    c
9     3    b
```

Create a dictionary of flag -> rules as well as a function to apply them:

```
def flag_filter(df, flag, rule_dict):
    rule = rule_dict[flag]
    if rule is None:
        return df
    return df.query(rule)

rule_dict = {
    0: None,                             # flag 0 returns the dataframe unfiltered
    1: "col2 != 'a'",                    # flag 1 = where column2 is not equal to "a"
    2: "col1 == 3 & col2 == ['b', 'c']"  # flag 2 = where column1 equals 3 AND column2 equals either "b" or "c"
}
```

Flag 0

```
subset = flag_filter(df, 0, rule_dict)
print(subset)

   col1 col2
0     0    b
1     3    c
2     1    a
3     0    d
4     3    c
5     3    a
6     3    a
7     3    a
8     1    c
9     3    b
```

Flag 1

```
subset = flag_filter(df, 1, rule_dict)
print(subset)

   col1 col2
0     0    b
1     3    c
3     0    d
4     3    c
8     1    c
9     3    b
```

Flag 2

```
subset = flag_filter(df, 2, rule_dict)
print(subset)

   col1 col2
1     3    c
4     3    c
9     3    b
```